# How prove that for each $x\in S$ there exist $m\leq [\frac{n+1}{4}]$ such thst $f(f(...f(x)...))=x$?

Tags: number-theory

For a given integer $n$ , let $S$ be a set of all odd natural numbers less than or equal to $n$ and relatively prime to $n$. For $x\in S$ define $f(x)$ to be the greatest odd divisor of $n-x$. Prove that :

a) for each $x\in S$ there exist $m\leq [\frac{n+1}{4}]$ such thst $f(f(...f(x)...))=x$ (where $[x]$ denote the greatest integer less that or equal to $x$).

b) if $n$ is prime and doesn't divide $2^k-1$ for every $k=1,2,...,n-2$, then the least $m$ from the part a) is equal to $[\frac {n+1}{4}]$.

---

Take n = 13, x = 7. Then f(x) is the greatest odd divisor of 6, i.e. 3. But then f(f(7)) = f(3) = 5, and then f(f(f(7))) = f(f(3)) = f(5) = 1, but f(1) = 3, so it'll just go 3 - 5 - 1 - 3 - 5 - 1 and never come back to 7?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Another counterexample would be $n=17, x=9$, since $f(9)$ is the biggest odd divisor of 8, which is 1, and $f(1)$ is the biggest odd divisor of 16, which is 1.

A set of counterexamples would be $n=2^{n+1}+1, x=2^{n}+1$ for $n\geq1$, since $f(2^n)=f(1)=1$, and it then will just loop in 1.